# Get the data at a time in Django and make it use through out the application

Tags: python, django

How to create a Project/ application scope variable in django will be loaded when I start the server and that variable will be accessible to all views in a app i,e. Application level

Comment: You can define the variable in `settings.py`, but basically every module will do, as long as you import the module properly.

Comment: What I want to know is,whenever I start the Django project

Comment: Whenever I start the Django project , it should be stored in memory and it can be used by all apps in my project

Comment: When ever am running the manage.py file I get the information from some external url.
How to store that information in memory and how to use that throughout the application in django